# ASP .NET MVC3 Razor Popup View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, entity-framework-4, popup

I am new to web development..

i have created views using Entity Framework in MVC3 Razor..
What i have done yet is,
i 1st created model(Clients) and DbContext(ClientDbContext) Classes.
then, i add controller with scaffolfind options

Template: Controller with read/Write actions and View, Using Entity Framework

Model Class: Clients

Data Context Class : ClientDbContext

Views : Razor(CSHTML)

It Creates the controller class and index, Detail, Delete, Delete Views...
After that i modified the index page for search and pagination...

All are working good...
in the index page i have create, edit, delete, detail links... 
When i click the links browser loads to that page and working good...

But i need to popup those views when i click the links in the index page...
i don't know how to do this... i studied many articles but i am confused... 
Please help me to solve this with an efficient manner...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you mean you want to have the create/update/delete views to be in a pop-up modal instead of redirecting to a new page?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a model pop-up within a page isn't something that can be done directly with ASP.NET MVC. You could do it yourself using javascript & css but I would strongly recommend using a JS UI framework to do this. [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) has a pop-up modal box, except they call it a dialog.

The docs for jQuery UI's dialog can be found [here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/). Have a look through the examples to see the fine details of how to set it up. But this is the basic flow of what you need to do:

- Download the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download/) files needed and include them on your page (CSS/JS files)
- Take the html from your create/update/delete views and put it on your index page, wrap them in a div with an appropriate id
- When the page loads use jquery ui to target your div's you want to be a popup

Things such as the link you want to make a dialog popup is set by passing options to the dialog initialize method, again the exact options and examples can be found on the docs page.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this : http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ to create a jQuery Dialog box.

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
          });
    </script>

    <div id="dialog">
         @using(Html.BeginForm()){
            @Html.EditorForModel()
           <input type='submit' value ='Submit'/>
        }
    </div>
```